# Apologizing for an accident that occurred outside the workplace

Tags: personal-problems

I have a colleague, let's call him Gary, who sits a few rows down from me and had an emotional support dog.  A lot of people in the office question whether this is truly a real "emotional support dog" because the dog is old. I've always defended Gary and the dog because I'm a strong believer in emotional support animals.  (My cousin actually trains emotional support animals for a living).

Last week when driving home, the dog darted in front of my car.  I slammed on the brakes, but unfortunately, the dog died.

I feel very bad for Gary's loss.  However, my boss is now requesting I issue a public apology.  I really don't feel I need to do this because:

- This wasn't my fault at all
- I ended up having to pay for my own car repair out of my own pocket
- My lawyer friend advised me that publicly apologizing could be inadvertently admitting fault
- This situation is already embarrassing enough

However, I also don't want to give people the impression that I'm heartless or that I'm one of the people in the office who have been questioning whether this is truly an emotional support animal.

Am I being too selfish in not wanting to apologize?  How can I express my remorse and support for emotional support animals, while not admitting fault?  Or should I just be quiet and let things simmer?

Comment: I don't think saying something like "*I am sorry for your loss*" is an admission of guilt.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I want to do that either as it's more of the opinion of public (in this case my office).

Comment: Have you apologised in private?

Comment: No I haven't talked about it with anyone today as I wanted to hear everyone else's thoughts on this.

Comment: You say outside of work, but was this outside of the company parking lot too?

Comment: If it did not happen at the workplace they cannot tell you what to do.

Comment: Did you talk to your boss about the position this puts you in?

Comment: @paparazzo Damn I missed that, good point!!

Comment: Please state your jurisdiction. Some places have [laws that prevent apologies from being treated as admissions of fault](https://www.theloop.ca/canadians-love-to-say-sorry-so-much-we-had-to-make-this-law/).

Comment: It likely does not change your unfortunate predicament, but it may be helpful to note two things: 1) emotional support animals are not considered service animals under Title II and Title III of the ADA, so laws regarding them vary by state, and 2) the ADA requires that service animals be under strict control at all times, physically tethered when possible, and things like unexpected barking and running are considered unacceptable behavior.

Comment: You're username is not very appropiate for this question. Gary had the best dog.

Comment: "Last week when driving home, the dog darted in front of my car. " That sounds like the dog was not under the owner's control; was the dog off-leash?  That is usually illegal in most places, and thus the fault for the accident would be the owner.

Comment: Was this in the company's parking lot? If so and if your boss still insists on bullying you with this issue, you should file a claim with the insurance company of your employer.

Comment: Listen to your lawyer.

Comment: It has been six months since you posted this. Can you tell us how it turned out?

Comment: @Mawg I do not want to go into the details, but there ended up with a huge blowout between several people including me. Gary was involved and for semi-unrelated reasons decided to resign/fired after he said some specific things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't a work issue. You should obviously apologize to the owner for running over his dog. But it isn't your fault that the dog wasn't properly controlled. Furthermore, you've accepted part of the fault by paying for the damage to your car instead of filing a claim against the negligent owner.

A private condolences to the owner is in order - but a public apology is not necessary; nobody else was hurt or impacted by the incident. If anyone takes issue with that, tell them that it's on attorney advice.

Comment: It's a work issue because his boss is forcing it into the workplace.

Comment: It wasn't OP's fault so they should not apologize but just express their sympathy. Apologizing is the same as admitting their fault.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I being too selfish in not wanting to apologize?

It sounds like you already apologized. It's unclear what you mean when you say your boss wants you to publicly apologize. Do you mean everyone is to gather in the office, and hear you apologize for the dog?

If it did not happen at the office I don't see why you should.

> How can I express my remorse and support for emotional support animals, while not admitting fault?

I would just say Gary, I am sorry I could not stop in time when the dog ran in front of my car. I did not see him and it is a very unfortunate situation.

> Or should I just be quiet and let things simmer?

Yes.

Answer (score 5):

Get Gary a card. In the card write:

> Gary,
>
> I am so sorry you lost Toby. I know he was an important companion for
> you. I wish there was something more I could have done to prevent the
> accident. I know Toby can’t be replaced, however I hope you can find
> other ways to receive the comfort and support Toby gave to you.
>
> Yours sincerely
>
> Ihave

Just hand the card to Gary and simply say “I’m sorry for your loss”.

Your lawyer may be right that apologizing could hurt you if Garry sues you, however, you are more likely to be sued if Garry thinks you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

There are precedents. Historically [Cúchulainn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%BA_Chulainn) killed an Irish Wolfhound belonging to a blacksmith and then made up for it to the distraught owner by taking over it's duties until a replacement could be reared.

So in lieu of some lame, ineffectual condolences you could offer to provide emotional support to the chap until he acquires a replacement, unsure what form that would take. A daily hug or two might suffice.

Cúchulainn didn't go around naked on all fours, so no tail wagging or licking would be required.

Comment: Sétanta, who became Cú Chulainn, was probably more suited to be a guard dog than an emotional support animal.

Comment: @BenMz most culture heroes were homicidal maniacs